# Adobe CQ Evaluation: Are there problems with Multi Site Manager / TarOptimizer?

Tags: java, content-management-system, adobe, aem

I work at a retailer and we consider to introduce CQ5 as a CMS.

However, after doing some research and talking to consultants it turns out, that there may be things that may be "complicated". Perhaps one of you can shed a little light on this.

The first thing is, we were told that when you use the Multi Site Manager to create multi language pages (about 80 languages) the update process can be as slow as half an hour until a change is ultimately published. Did someone of you experience something similar?

The other thing is, that the TarOptimizer has pretty long running times. I was told that runs that take up to 24 hours are not uncommon. Again my question: Did someone of you had such a problem or has an explanation for this?

I am really looking forward to your response.

Answer (score 0):

These are really 2 separate question, but I'll address them based on my experience.

The update process for creating new multi-language pages will vary based on the number of languages, and also the number of publish instances and web-servers (assuming you're using dispatcher to cache) you are running.  This is because the replication process is where the bottleneck is (at least in my experience), and as such if you're trying to push out a large amount of content across a large number of publishers with a large number of front-end web-servers whose cache needs to be cleared, there will be some delay in getting this to happen since replication is an asynchronous process.  The longest delay I've seen for this has been in the 10-15 minute range, that was with 12 publishers and 12 front end webservers, but this comes with the obvious caveat that your mileage may vary.

For the Tar Optimzation job, I'd encourage you to take a look at [this page](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/core/administering/persistence_managers.html#Maximizing%20the%20Performance%20of%20Tar%20Optimization) as it has a  lot of good info about the Tar Optizer job and how to tune it.  The job can take a long time to run when you have a large repository, especially on an instance with a large number of write operations, but the run times can be configured so that it only runs during a given time period, and it will pick up where it left off the night before if the total run time is longer than the allowed run time.  By default, it runs from 2-5 am each night, so if it takes more than that 3 hour period, it will continue where it left off the next night, allowing it to optimize the entire repository over a period of a few days if needed.